# Find the best optimization vmoptions Intellij 2016

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, jvm, intellij-idea-2016

I m using IntelliJ 2016, by default the vmoptions contains :

```
-server
-Xms128m
-Xmx512m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-ea
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow
```

I would like to customize IntelliJ to make it faster.
Here the properties for my system.

[image]

I m using : Java as language,  Apache Camel as Framework

Is there an optimal configuration ?

Thxs

Answer (score 2):

I use this contains;

I think you like use this.

```
-ea
-server
-Xms2G
-Xmx4096M
-Xss2m
-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=2G
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=1G
-XX:MetaspaceSize=512m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:+DoEscapeAnalysis
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-XX:LargePageSizeInBytes=256m
-XX:+UseCodeCacheFlushing
-XX:ParallelGCThreads=8
-XX:+DisableExplicitGC
-XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent
-XX:+PrintGCDetails
-XX:+PrintFlagsFinal
-XX:+AggressiveOpts
-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=60
-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
-XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled
-XX:+UseAdaptiveGCBoundary
-XX:+UseSplitVerifier
-XX:CompileThreshold=10000
-XX:+OptimizeStringConcat
-XX:+UseStringCache
-XX:+UseFastAccessorMethods
-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow
-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=lcd
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
-Xverify:none

-XX:ErrorFile=$USER_HOME/java_error_in_idea_%p.log
-XX:HeapDumpPath=$USER_HOME/java_error_in_idea.hprof
-Xbootclasspath/a:../lib/boot.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the size of your projects and the technologies/frameworks/languages they're using. The best solution to dealing with slowness is to report it: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241235-Reporting-performance-problems

That said, if you have a lot of free physical memory (and you likely do), you could increase the Xmx parameter to e.g. 2g, that might speed things up.

Comment: I m using : Java as language 
Apache Camel as Framework.
I tried to put -Xmx1G but it doesn't work

Comment: What doesn't work? Please note that to use large memory, you should start a 64-bit Java (idea64.exe/vmoptions)

Comment: Intellij does not want to open when i put -Xmx1G, 
I thought there would be an equation based on the RAM on the machine, to modify the vm arguments.

Comment: Do you start idea64.exe?

Comment: Yes and i set IDEA_JDK_64 =  .../jdk1.8 and change in the idea64.exe.vmoptions , the value -Xmx2G. But intellij still running with 725Mo.

Comment: Strange. Could you please provide idea.log (Help | Show log)? (you can do it privately in https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues#newissue)

Answer (score 1):

First,

If you have a 64 bits as OS, it s better to launch idea64.exe version.

- idea64 (Version 2016) must run with a JDK 8 (64 bits)
- SET IDEA_JDK_64 = ../path of jdk8
- Edit idea64.exe.vmoptions  "-Xmx1024m"

[image]